# How to solve this android studio project error?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Daemon startup failed Please check if you installed the Windows
> Universal C Runtime.

Have you updated your Runtime ?

Download: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows